# How to make foreach statement from array in RN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Assume I have an array and I want to display as much buttons as array length. How to make easiest

Comment: please share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to assign array values to the map statement

```
import {
  Button
} from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
  const names = ["mark", "steve", "jason"]
  return (
    {names.map(name => <Button>{name}</Button>)}
  );
}
```